# How to pass a dict to a unit test using parameterized?

Tags: python, django, paramterized

I have a list of dicts:

```
MY_LIST = [ 
    { 'key1': {'a': 1, 'b':2 } },
    { 'key2': {'a': 1, 'b':2 } } 
]
```

How do I pass the dict to a django unit test using [parameterized](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/)? E.g.

```
@parameterized.expand(MY_LIST):
def test_mytest(self, dict_item):
    print(dict_item.items())
```

Results in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` because the dict is being converted to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs:

```
The @parameterized and @parameterized.expand decorators accept a list or iterable of tuples or param(...), or a callable which returns a list or iterable
```

So I would try to convert `MY_LIST` to:

```
MY_LIST = [ 
    ({ 'key1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},),
    ({ 'key2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},), 
]
```

Which makes it a list of tuples that contain a single parameter to apply to the method you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a NamedTuple instead to give your parameters keys

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class TestParameters(NamedTuple):
  firstParam: str
  secondParam: int
  
@parameterized.expand([TestParameters(
  firstParam="firstParam",
  secondParam="secondParam"
  )
]
def test(self, firstParam, secondParam):
  ...
```

if you need it as a dict for a differect reason, you can also do this

```
@parameterized.expand([TestParameters(
  firstParam="firstParam",
  secondParam="secondParam"
  )
]
def test(self, *args):
  test_params = TestParams(*args)._asdict()
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just packaging the dicts into a list (with just the one dict inside). Like:

```
MY_LIST = [[d] for d in MY_LIST]
```

Afterwards you might expect to unpack it (like: `dict_item[0]`), but that's not the case